People sit in front of TV to discuss the deaths they caused
The movie begins with a couple fighting.  Its between an Asian woman and a middle aged man.  They pull off and suddenly the school calls him.  They continue to fight.  But as it proceeds he ends up murdering and then ends up in this room with other people who have murdered or committed suicide.  They all sit in front of a television and discuss whats happening.  They must then relive the circumstances to which led up to their choices over and over.  This man goes to speak to his counselor that is just a television.   Then eventually he is able to break into this hatch where he can experience through the eyes of others how he was treating them and what was happening.  He is able to finally talk someone else into trying to help him not commit a crime.  In the end he ends up saving that woman from killing herself giving her the life she never hadadvak and he is then content with being there.   The end of the movie ends up showing his family missing him and appreciating him.
This is what I remember....
I am pretty sure I saw it on Netflix but cannot find it through any internet searches.   Can anyone please help?

You are looking for Cruel and Unusual (2014)


Cruel and Unusual is a 2014 Canadian surrealistic thriller written by
  Merlin Dervisevic. It is the debut feature for Merlin Dervisevic, who
  also directed the film. Starring David Richmond-Peck, Bernadette
  Saquibal, and Michelle Harrison, the film follows a man wrongly
  condemned for killing his wife, who finds himself in a mysterious
  institution where he is sentenced to relive her death for eternity.
  Distributed by Entertainment One in Canada and Candy Factory Films in
  the United States, the film was theatrically released on 24 May 2014.

It is indeed a movie which is featured on Netflix.
And here's a trailer on YouTube.
